# extract the last 2 fields regardless of size

Tags: regex, splunk

I have been trying to get the last "two fields" of the following strings:

```
cc-api-data.bar.bar
external-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net
fbcdn.net
```

for the first 2 strings, I would like to only get the "bar.bar" and "fbcdn.net." However, for the last string, I want it to match the whole thing since it has all i want.

I am pretty confident i could do this in a simple script but I am trying to use regex in this case. I can only get the last part of the string on the last string but not the whole thing. And I cannot tell the regex which field to take.
I literally just want the last two fields, no matter how many delimiters there are.

Any suggestions or is it even possible

Comment: You can use [`[^.]+\.[^.]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/izMl1w/1) - note I had to add `\s` to the class in the link only to show you correct matches. Since you're matching against each string individually, you won't need to do that.

Comment: If those addresses show up in free text you may want to us `/s` as (additional) separator: `[^.]+\.[^.]+(?:\s|$)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that we might want an expression that would have a `$` anchor similar to:

```
([^.]*)\.([^.]*)$
```

towards the right side of our strings.

#### [Please see the demo for additional explanation](https://regex101.com/r/sylaKq/1/)

> I was wondering how does regex know to get
>   only the part before the last period. Is it because it grabs any
>   character thats not a "." and because it is at the end of the line?
>   why couldnt it grab the first octet?

Good question, also a bit difficult to explain, by playing this demo, we can watch the many steps prior to getting to our matches:

[Steps of Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/sylaKq/1/debugger)

It would start char by char and test it against our expression, it would pass for our rules in the expression, **yet in early chars or octet**, once it would hit the `$` end anchor, **those early chars or octet** would fail, because our last **end of string rule** has been broken.

Comment: Thats simple and amazing. I was wondering how does regex know to get only the part before the last period. Is it because it grabs any character thats not a "." and because it is at the end of the line? why couldnt it grab the first octet?

Comment: I see now. It basically tests each pair until it reaches the one that is at the end of the line to comply with $. I see your regex works on v. 1. Is that the defacto version to use? Using version 365 does not yield the same result.